# How to run python script on my server?

Tags: python

I have a server hosting by Blueshot. I have been using php to get post variables from iPhone... But now I have to use python to get post variable from iPhone. I wrote something like this

```
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting

print "Content-type: text/html"
print

print """
<html>

<head><title>Sample CGI Script</title></head>

<body>

  <h3> Sample CGI Script </h3>
"""

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
message = form.getvalue("message", "(no message)")

print """

  <p>Previous message: %s</p>

  <p>form

  <form method="post" action="index.cgi">
    <p>message: <input type="text" name="message"/></p>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
""" % message
```

And uploaded to my server but it doesn't work...If I navigate to the page then it just shows the source code.. I don't know whether or not python is installed on my server (I believe python might be installed as default)..How do I check if python is runnable on my server and if not how can I run python scripts on my server? All I want to do is to get POST variables from iPhone (I know how to send the variables from iPhone) Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a small checklist of things to check when CGI scripts aren't working:

- Is it in a `cgi-bin` (or equivalent) folder?
- Is it executable?
- Is it readable?
- Does it have a hashbang?
- Is your server set up to process CGI scripts?

Here's a sample CGI script you can use for testing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi; cgi.test()
```

Name it `test.py`, put it somewhere in `cgi-bin`, and make sure it's executable:

```
$ chmod a+rx test.py
```

Some web servers only recognize CGI scripts with certain extensions, so if `.py` doesn't work, you may want to try `.cgi`.

Comment: hashbang is important, +1. I always use it, but guess not everyone does

Answer (score 0):

This is a webserver configuration problem not a programming issue.

If you're running Apache, this might work:

```
chmod 755 myscript.py
ln -s myscript.py myscript.cgi
```

Then put this in your .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

If you can't run the `ln` command because of no shell access, just upload with the .cgi extension to begin with. Or, as icktoofay said, put it in your cgi-bin folder, then you won't need the .htaccess modification either.

Comment: Then how to change the configuration?

Comment: @icktoofay: I know, I was typing, I'm slow :^\