# Would my simple console based python code work in the web?

Tags: python, web

Will the simple Python code work on the web-server(with Apache2 installed). The code is save as let's say hello.py.

```
def hello():
    print ("Hello there Python!!")
```

It's just an example. This code will work in the console. Will this code work on the web? My question is: Would I console based application will work on the web saved as .py extension?

Comment: Just think. Where are the HTTP headers? Where is the URL mapping?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)? Do you have Python installed, etc. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645384/how-to-run-python-script-on-my-server) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No...

Because a web page works over HTTP protocol, that means, your server needs to is:

- receive HTTP request
- process that request
- create response
- send your response back via HTTP

By using python, you can only process input data (a part of step 2 of the list).

As for the solution, you must use a web framework which will handle the other parts and use a web server (like apache).

There exist good web frameworks like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Web.py](http://webpy.org/), but it is better you check your requirements and choose a proper framework.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is vague. You should try reading more about using python as a server side scripting language and come back when you have some more concrete and specific questions. Try and google "Using python as a server side scripting language" and check out this link http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html